# DIY Bluetooth speaker circuit won't turn on

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, diy

I'm making a Bluetooth speaker and made a schematic which I'm using to follow to build the speaker.

[image]

It's loosely based on this DIY video I saw online, here's the picture of the relevant parts I copied:

[image]

Problem is though that when I tried the second picture out (proper looking schematic) it worked normally for my speaker (in my case I used 4S batteries each 3.7V) but when I tried out my schematic with the step up converter, it just stopped working.

Now my intention was to step up the 12V input to 16.8V for the battery board and the Bluetooth board too (Bluetooth board can handle higher voltages so it's cool) but with the way I did it, it was wrong. I even tried to plug in a power supply of 12V but it started making some high pitched noise, fortunately there was nothing burning.

Any ideas with how I can fix this issue?

EDIT: Links to the Bluetooth Amp and the Boost Converter for additional info:
https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Bluetooth-5-0-TPA3116D2-Digital-2-1-Audio-Amplifier-Board-100W-50W-50W-DC-12-GS/333643187264?_trksid=p2485497.m4902.l9144

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00HV43UOG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Regarding terminology, that is not a schematic, only some kind of block diagram / wiring diagram. Would you please mention the module part numbers, because we can't know what specific modules you use and what their specifications are. Have you checked that the step up module can provide enough current for the speaker module?

Comment: Thank you for the correction. And yeah this is the Bluetooth amp: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Bluetooth-5-0-TPA3116D2-Digital-2-1-Audio-Amplifier-Board-100W-50W-50W-DC-12-GS/333643187264?_trksid=p2485497.m4902.l9144

Output max current for the step up converter is 10A (Max voltage boost from step up is 35V)

Comment: Part number/Name of the step up?

Comment: DC-DC Boost Converter, the product on amazon: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00HV43UOG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1